# Logging Scopes in ASP.Net Core's Debug Logger

Tags: logging, asp.net-core, scope

I'm working with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and I've turned on logging scopes for the console output [according to the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#log-scopes).

That's working well but I don't see a way to enable scopes for debug output. Am I missing something or do I just have to implement my own debug logger to see scopes?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I stumbled across the answer to my own question after I had given up. Turns out adding [full support for scopes](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/682) is on the list for the [2.1.0 milestone](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/milestone/24).